# Dynamic LINQ using linqkit

Tags: linq, dynamic-linq, predicatebuilder, linqkit

Following this example from http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

```
IQueryable<Product> SearchProducts (params string[] keywords)
{
  var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<Product>();

  foreach (string keyword in keywords)
  {
    string temp = keyword;
    predicate = predicate.Or (p => p.Description.Contains (temp));
  }
  return dataContext.Products.Where (predicate);
}
```

I have a similiar requirement except that firstly I have to do an AND query and secondly , unlike the above example, I have a bunch of  field names and a value to search in each of them. The field names and the values both are unknown till the user passes them through. I ended up doing something like the code below which works but obviously is very tightly coupled.

```
 IEnumerable<someClass> qry = context.someClass;
 var pb = PredicateBuilder.True<someClass>();

 foreach (customClass rule in Filters)
            {


                switch ( rule.field)
                    {
                    case "FirstName":
                            pb = pb.And(p=>p.FirstName.Contains(rule.data));
                            break;
                    case "LastName":
                            pb = pb.And(p=>p.LastName.Contains(rule.data));
                            break;
                    case "City":
                           pb = pb.And(p=>p.City.Contains(rule.data));
                           break;

                    }

                qry.AsQueryable().Where(pb);
            }
            return qry;
```

As can be seen from above the Rule class has a field and data property. What would be ideal is if I could dynamically create the predicatebuilder , something like

```
filterClause = "p=>p." + rule.field + ".Contains(" + rule.data + ")";


pb = pb.And(filterClause);

qry.AsQueryable().Where(pb);
```

Thanks in advance for any inputs

Comment: thats look fine to me, are you getting any error with it??

Comment: No I am looking for a better way to achieve the same result..if it is possible that is

Comment: Did you mean the second code bit with filterClause looks fine to you ? Well the predicatebuilder only accepts function arguments so the string argument doesnt work. Throws an error

Comment: You may want to look at this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/2297519/201648. It looks like Dynamic Linq could be the answer to your question - http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

Comment: I'm encountering exactly the same problem.

Comment: Without LinqKit even, you can say condition like `from x in xs where x.ok? x.a : x.snd? x.b : x.c select ...` or use `let tmp = x?a:b select tmp...` and EF will understand that.