# Modify linq query at runtime

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, extension-methods

**Problem statement**

Say I have a query which searches the names of people:

```
var result = (from person in container.people select person)
             .Where(p => p.Name.Contains(some_criterion)
```

This will be translated to a SQL query containing the following like clause:

```
WHERE NAME LIKE '%some_criterion%'
```

This has some performance implications, as the database is unable to effectively use the index on the name column (index scan v.s. index seek if I'm not mistaken).

To remedy this, I can decide to just StartsWith() instead, generating a query using a like clause  like:

```
WHERE NAME LIKE 'some_criterion%'
```

Which enables SQL server to use the index seek and delivering performance at the cost of some functionality.

I'd like to be able to provide the user with a choice: defaulting the behavior to use StartsWith, but if the user want the 'added flexibility' of searching using Contains(), than that should used.

**What have I tried**

I thought this to be trivial and went on and implemented an extension method on string. But of course, LINQ does not accept this and an exception is thrown.

Now, of course I can go about and use an if or switch statement and create a query for each of the cases, but I'd much rather solve this 'on a higher level' or more generically.
In short: using an if statement to differentiate between use cases isn't feasible due to the complexity of the real-life application. This would lead to alot of repetition and clutter. I'd really like to be able to encapsulate the varying behavior (Contains, StartsWith, EndsWith) somehow.

**Question**

Where should I look or what should I look for? Is this a case for composability with IQueryables? I'm quite puzzled!

Comment: Criterium. Singular of criteria.

Comment: That would be "criterion".

Comment: Aha, ok. Wasn't aware. Overextending rules applying to my own language to English ;)

Comment: I think, you are looking for generating lambdas at runtime. I must say this would require some more work, more testing etc. See this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297502/dynamically-build-linq-lambda-expression

Comment: Then these comments are worth _something_. (:

Comment: @Oxymoron look at my update, I demonstrate how to encapsulate the string functions as per your update (I'd really like to be able to encapsulate the varying behavior (Contains, StartsWith, EndsWith) somehow).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rather than overcomplicate things, how about just using an if statement?

```
var query = from person in container.people 
            select person;

if (userWantsStartsWith)
{
    query = from p in query
            where p.Name.Contains(some_criterion)
            select p;
}
else
{
    query = from p in query
            where p.Name.StartsWith(some_criterion)
            select p;
}
```

**Update**

If you really need something more complex try looking at [LinqKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx).  It allows you to do the following.

```
var stringFunction = Lambda.Expression((string s1, string s2) => s1.Contains(s2));

if (userWantsStartsWith)
{
    stringFunction = Lambda.Expression((string s1, string s2) => s1.StartsWith(s2));
}

var query = from p in container.people.AsExpandable()
            where stringFunction.Invoke(p.Name, some_criterion)
            select p;
```

I believe this fulfils your requirement of

> I'd really like to be able to encapsulate the varying behavior
>   (Contains, StartsWith, EndsWith) somehow.

Comment: Wow I was just gonna write the same ... Yeah, I agree - keep it simple.

Comment: @Doc : +1 for more simplicity

Comment: The real life queries are quite huge and unioned with several others. This, like my problem states, isn't the solution I'm looking for.

Comment: Your comment says that you don't want to build a new query for each case.  This isn't doing that, it's building a query based on your criteria.  You don't need a brand new query, you can just add where filters based on if statements.  Much more simple than playing with lambdas.

Comment: The only thing that varies is the StartsWith/Contains/EndsWith, and does so in alot of different locations. I'd much rather encapsulate that behavior somehow. This solution just isn't feasible for the real-life scenario. Multiple columns can be searched in every case et cetera.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I'm going to look in to that! Looks promising :-)

Comment: You're welcome, remember to come back here and tick accept if you've found this helpful :-)

Comment: I'm working on a possible solution at the moment, not quite as stated in the OP, but rather with an extension to IQueryable and Expression.Lambda. It's not quite finished and has some issues, but accomplishes what I need.

Comment: Issues are solved, had some trouble combining multiple predicates, but thanks to this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/meek/archive/2008/05/02/linq-to-entities-combining-predicates.aspx article that is solved as well :)

Answer (score 2):

You can dynamically alter the query before enumerating it.

```
var query = container.people.AsQueryable();

if (contains)
{
    query = query.Where(p => p.Name.Contains(filter));
}
else
{
    query = query.Where(p => p.Name.StartsWith(filter));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try dis:

```
var result = (from person in container.people select person)
                .Where(p => some_bool_variable ? p.Name.Contains(some_criterium) : p.Name.StartsWith(some_criterium));
```

*The real life queries are quite huge and unioned with several others. This, like my problem states, isn't te solution I'm looking for*

Sinse your queries are huge: can't you just define stored procedure that handles everything and call it with specific to query parameters (probably several stored procedures that are called by main, e.g. one of em searches by Name, another - by Age, have different sort order and so on to keep code clear)?