# Is it possible to create this linq statement dynamically?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I'm creating a rule validation class - nothing fancy.

I want to set properties like this:

```
public int MaxLoanAmount { get; set; }
```

The data would be validated like this. _app refers to data injected via the constructor.

```
bool MaxLoanAmountValid
{
   get { return _app.LoanAmount >= MaxLoanAmount; }
}
```

I could construct some if logic to test if each of my properties are set, validate them and return the result, however I would like to try and be a little more clever than that.

I wonder if it is possible to build a dynamic expression, so when MaxLoanAmount is set, I add "MaxLoanAmountValid", and so on "MaxLoanAmountValid AND MinLoanAmountValid" etc.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: show some examples on how would you use it. Some unit tests for next system will be perfect. You might consider using [FLEE](http://flee.codeplex.com/) . Examples include: `context.CompileDynamic("sqrt(a) + pi")`

Comment: Looks like time to get System.Attribute and reflection to me, or as @Ilya implied a set of rules and an eval equivalent. Once you have mechanism then look at describing it in Linq.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can dynamically build a Linq expression tree either using the .NET APIs or one of several free tools that make the job easier.  Some can parse a string into an expression, so all you have to do is build the string.  See the links in the answer to an almost identical question: [Dynamically Build Linq Lambda Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297502/dynamically-build-linq-lambda-expression)

If you want to be even more "clever" you may get dynamically the current property name in its Set method using Reflection like this `MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name`.