# C# dynamic predicate building

Tags: c#, linq, collections, predicate

Is there a way to build a predicate expression dynamically depending on some value?

```cs
class ClassObj
{
    public int SomeValue { get; set; }
    public int SomeOtherValue { get; set; }
}
```

For example, if I have `int val` and a `List<ClassObj>`. If my `val` equals to 5, for example, I'd like my list to keep only objects whose `SomeValue` is equal to 5. If my `val` equals to something else, I'd like my list to keep objects whose `SomeOtherValue` is equal to that number.

Comment: Take a look at the [ExpressionTree](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/)

Comment: You can follow [this amazing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2297519/6797509)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```cs
static Func<ClassObj, bool> GetValueFilter(int val) => val switch {
    5 => x => x.SomeValue == 5, // or == val in the more general case
    _ => x => x.SomeOtherValue == val,
};
```

(or return `Expression<Func<ClassObj, bool>>` if this is for EF etc)

with usage:

```cs
var filtered = source.Where(GetValueFilter(val));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Func<ClassObject, bool> predicate;
if (val == 5)
{
    predicate = obj => obj.SomeValue == 5;
}
else
{
    predicate = obj => obj.SomeOtherValue == val;
}

var result = yourList.Where(predicate);
```

Of course, for your example you could use a single expression:

```
yourList.Where(obj => val == 5 ? obj.SomeValue == 5 : obj.SomeOtherValue == val);
```