# Linq Query multiples tables join with array of varying table names

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have an List containing some Entity names. These List may be varying each time and I need to join the entities in the list each other.

How can I do this dynamically in linq?

Examples:

#### `[A,B,C]`

```cs
from itemOne in A 
join itemTwo in B on itemOne.Id = itemTwo.Id 
join itemThree in C on itemOne.Id = itemThree.Id
```

#### `[A,B,C,D]`

```cs
from itemOne in A 
join itemTwo in B on itemOne.Id = itemTwo.Id 
join itemThree in C on itemOne.Id = itemTwo.Id 
join itemFour in D on itemOne.id = itemFour.Id
```

Comment: I believe that the queries are expressions. You can build your own dynamic expressions, and then pass those in as the query.

Comment: Based on what condition do you want to decide which joins should be performed? Are there only a limited number of different joins, or are there a hundreds of join combination that you need to support?

Comment: there wil be limited number of joins but it may be around 50 so I cant make it one single query because it affects performance. Also the joins will be based on a filter that is getting passed from client side

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297502/dynamically-build-linq-lambda-expression

Comment: @AmeerPappay The Linq does define an extension method called [Join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.join?view=net-5.0) on `IEnumarble`. The biggest problem here is the return type: `A.Join(B, itemOne => itemOne.Id, itemTwo => itemTwo.Id, (itemOne, ItemTwo) =>  ???)` What would be your return type which is composable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you would resort to anonymous types, but apparently there's no way to dynamically construct those. If you don't have anything against [ExpandoObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dynamic.expandoobject?view=net-5.0), you can try use it instead of anonymous types.

so, suppose you want to join a bunch of lists and declare a `List<List<MyEntity>>`. Then you'd be building an object like so:

```
{
i0: items[0] // added on first run - you need to have at least two lists in your join array
i1: items[1] // added on first run - you need to have at least two lists in your join array
...
iN: items[N] // added on each pass an joined with items[0]
}
```

Since [.Join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.join?view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_Join__4_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___1__System_Func___0___2__System_Func___1___2__System_Func___0___1___3__) requires a key selector, we need to pick a list from the interim `ExpandoObject`. Looking at your example I assumed you'd be fine to always use the first list as your matching source.

You could probably do this with only `ExpressionTrees` all the way, but to simplify the code a bit (and allow debugging while I'm at it) I opted to wrap some of the logic into extensions:

```cs
public static class Extensions 
{
    public static ExpandoObject AddValue(this ExpandoObject expando, object value)
    {
        var dict = (IDictionary<string, object>)expando;
        var key = $"i{dict.Count}"; // that was the easiest way to keep track of what's already in. You would probably find a way to do it better
        dict.Add(key, value);
        return expando;
    }

    public static ExpandoObject NewObject<T>(this ExpandoObject expando, T value1, T value2)
    {
        var dict = (IDictionary<string, object>)expando;
        dict.Add("i0", value1);
        dict.Add("i1", value2);
        return expando;
    }
}
```

and the you could do something along these lines:

```cs
class Program
{
    class MyEntity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public MyEntity(int id, string name)
        {
            Id = id; Name = name;
        }
    }

    static List<ExpandoObject> Join<TSource, TDest>(List<List<TSource>> items, Expression<Func<TSource, int>> srcAccessor, Expression<Func<ExpandoObject, int>> intermediaryAccessor, Expression<Func<TSource, TSource, ExpandoObject>> outerResultSelector)
    {
        var joinLambdaType = typeof(ExpandoObject);            
        Expression<Func<ExpandoObject, TSource, ExpandoObject>> innerResultSelector = (expando, item) => expando.AddValue(item);
        
        var joinMethod = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods().Where(m => m.Name == "Join").First().MakeGenericMethod(typeof(TSource), typeof(TSource), typeof(int), joinLambdaType);
        var toListMethod = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods().Where(m => m.Name == "ToList").First().MakeGenericMethod(typeof(TDest));


        var joinCall = Expression.Call(joinMethod,
                                Expression.Constant(items[0]),
                                Expression.Constant(items[1]),
                                srcAccessor,
                                srcAccessor,
                                outerResultSelector);
        joinMethod = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods().Where(m => m.Name == "Join").First().MakeGenericMethod(typeof(TDest), typeof(TSource), typeof(int), joinLambdaType); // from now on we'll be joining ExpandoObject with MyEntity
        for (int i = 2; i < items.Count; i++) // skip the first two
        {
            joinCall =
                Expression.Call(joinMethod,
                                joinCall,
                                Expression.Constant(items[i]),
                                intermediaryAccessor,
                                srcAccessor,
                                innerResultSelector);
        }

        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<List<ExpandoObject>>>(Expression.Call(toListMethod, joinCall));
        return lambda.Compile()();
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        List<List<MyEntity>> items = new List<List<MyEntity>> {
            new List<MyEntity> {new MyEntity(1,"test1_1"), new MyEntity(2,"test1_2")},
            new List<MyEntity> {new MyEntity(1,"test2_1"), new MyEntity(2,"test2_2")},
            new List<MyEntity> {new MyEntity(1,"test3_1"), new MyEntity(2,"test3_2")},
            new List<MyEntity> {new MyEntity(1,"test4_1"), new MyEntity(2,"test4_2")}
        };

        Expression<Func<MyEntity, MyEntity, ExpandoObject>> outerResultSelector = (i, j) => new ExpandoObject().NewObject(i, j); // we create a new ExpandoObject and populate it with first two items we join
        Expression<Func<ExpandoObject, int>> intermediaryAccessor = (expando) => ((MyEntity)((IDictionary<string, object>)expando)["i0"]).Id; // you could probably get rid of hardcoding this by, say, examining the first key in the dictionary
        
        dynamic cc = Join<MyEntity, ExpandoObject>(items, i => i.Id, intermediaryAccessor, outerResultSelector);

        var test1_1 = cc[0].i1;
        var test1_2 = cc[0].i2;

        var test2_1 = cc[1].i1;
        var test2_2 = cc[1].i2;
    }
}
```